# react-bootstrap Carousel.js

Tags: carousel, react-bootstrap

I have written a simple .js file using react library react-bootstrap Carousel.js to create a uncontrolled carousel , but the images instead of coming as a slide are coming one after other vertically. Posting the code below. Can you help with debugging the same.

```
App.jsx
-----------

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';

import writing from './writing.jpg' ;
import grammer from './grammer.jpg' ;
import listening from './listening.jpg' ;
import reading from './reading.jpg' ;

import {Carousel}  from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      direction: null
    };
    }

  render() {
    const { index, direction } = this.state;
    return (

          <Carousel controls={false} >

          <Carousel.Item >

             <img src={grammer} alt="grammer" width={300} height={100} />
          </Carousel.Item>

          <Carousel.Item>
             <img src={listening} alt="listen" width={300} height={100} />
          </Carousel.Item>


          <Carousel.Item>
             <img width={300} height={100} alt="reading" src={reading} />

          </Carousel.Item>

              <Carousel.Item>
             <img width={300} height={100} alt="reading" src={writing} />

          </Carousel.Item>

          </Carousel>

    );
  }
}

export default App;



Index.js
----------
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();


and under index.html I have element below:

 <div id="root"></div>
```

So, after running this code, images are loading to the page, but carousel behavior is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just today and I saw this unanswered post, so I thought it would be a good idea to write how I solved my issue :

In my case, the carousel images were aligned vertically because I didn't include correctly the bootstrap stylesheets. Here are the steps I followed :

> **1.** go to https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/
>
> **2.** find the newest stylesheets and copy them to clipboard. The latest releases to this date are :
>
> ```
>     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
>
>     <!-- Optional theme -->
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
> ```
>
> **3.** paste them inside the `<head>` part of your `index.html` file. Now if you save all and reload your react app, it should be good.

Hope this would help anyone having the same issue !

Answer (score 0):

FYI with `bootstrap-4-react` you don't need to add the CSS files yourself. https://bootstrap-4-react.com/#documentation/components/carousel